# bash script to start another script in a tmux session

Tags: bash, tmux

I have a bash script that continuously outputs some information when run. I need to

1. Automatically run this when my system boots.
2. Monitor this output and control it every once in a while remotely, using ssh.

For this purpose, I would like to use tmux. So how do I approach this? For simplicity, let's say my shell script is this:

**filename: start.bash**

```
#!/bin/bash
# just an example for simplicity    
watch date
```

I need another script that runs this in tmux and be able to attach to this when I need, later. I am struggling at the part where I need to create a new tmux session with a name and make it run another shell script. Once I have this working, I can put this in another shell script and take care of the rest of the stuff. That is easy, I think. Can someone give me an example for this specific step please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this many ways.

You can do it after you've created the session either with send-keys:

```
tmux new -s "remote" -d
tmux send-keys -t "remote" "start.bash" C-m
tmux attach -t "remote" -d
```

Or through the shell:

```
tmux new -s "remote" -d "/bin/bash"
tmux run-shell -t "remote:0" "start.bash"
tmux attach -t "remote" -d
```

Answer (score 0):

Start a tmux session on the server and do not close it. It will keep running on the server. From your client computer you will be able to ssh in and run

```
tmux attach
```

to reconnect to whatever you had running in the tmux session. To start it at boot time if you reboot the server start tmux from a shell script that runs from /etc/rc.local